# Beginner java, "Required: int. Found: Boolean"?

Tags: java

Here's my code. I can't figure out what I messed up.
It says age is a boolean instead of an int and I don't know why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class F_DoIRemember {

    public static void main(String args[]){
      int age;
      Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What is your age?");
      age = inp.nextInt();
              switch(age){

                  case(age<5):
                      System.out.println("Are you learning how to tie your shoes?");

                  case(age==5):
                      System.out.println("You know how to tie your shoes!");

                  case(age>5):
                      System.out.println("YOU BETTER KNOW HOW TO TIE YOUR SHOES!");
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: You can't use a switch statement like that ("that" = a boolean expression). Consider reading a tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: `switch` statement is not like `CASE` from SQL. Review the basics in the link provided by Jeroen.

Comment: It is not say `age` is a boolean. It is saying `age<5` is a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

```
switch(age){
```

Would check for the values of the `age`. Since the data type for the `age` is int, it would always want an `int` value from your to check againt. But you're providing a bool value, `(age > 5)` would result into a `bool` value.

Conditions are not allowed in the `case`.

Either change `age` to bool (get input somewhere else from the user), or use it as

```
case 5: 
   System.out.println("Are you learning how to tie your shoes?");
   break;
```

You can use this condition somewhere else, but not in the `case` label.

Since you're using dynamic values,

```
age = inp.nextInt();
```

Which won't be same always, use

```
if(age > 5) {
   // code
} else if(age ==5) {
   // code
} else { // don't need to use (age < 5)
   // code
}
```

I think, you really need to be using this one instead of `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) requires that `case` expressions be [constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

```
SwitchLabel:
    case ConstantExpression :
    case EnumConstantName :
    default :
```

and

> A compile-time *constant expression* is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type String (§15.16)
> - ...

---

`(age<5)` is not a constant expression.  Use `if (age < 5) { ... } else if (age == 5) { ... } else { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all What is `switch` : **javadoc** says-

Unlike `if-then` and `if-then-else` statements, the `switch` statement can have a number of possible execution paths. A `switch` works with the `byte, short, char, and int primitive data types`. It also works with `enumerated types`.

Now in your example what you did is took some user-input which is of type `int`and passes it to the `switch` case which is acceptable after that what you did is a wrong.

The switch syntax says :

```
switch (expr) {
  case c1:
        statements // do these if expr == c1
        break;
  case c2: 
        statements // do these if expr == c2
        break;
  case c2:
  case c3:
  case c4:         //  Cases can simply fall thru.
        statements // do these if expr ==  any of c's
        break;
  . . .
  default:
        statements // do these if expr != any above
}
```

The `case` keyword must be followed by an value and a colon.

What you did is mixed the concept of `if-then-else` statements, the `switch` statement

What you thought of doing in your case is inside switch do something like

```
if(age<5)
   System.out.println("Are you learning how to tie your shoes?");

else if(age==5)
   System.out.println("You know how to tie your shoes!");

else
   System.out.println("YOU BETTER KNOW HOW TO TIE YOUR SHOES!");
```

which is not allowed by using these codes

```
case(age<5):
System.out.println("Are you learning how to tie your shoes?");

case(age==5):
System.out.println("You know how to tie your shoes!");

case(age>5):
System.out.println("YOU BETTER KNOW HOW TO TIE YOUR SHOES!");
```

Please [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score -1):

`(age<5)` returns boolean but the case statement accepts int.

try something like:

```
switch(age){

                  case 4:
                      System.out.println("Are you learning how to tie your shoes?");

                  case 5:
                      System.out.println("You know how to tie your shoes!");

                  case 6:
                      System.out.println("YOU BETTER KNOW HOW TO TIE YOUR SHOES!");
           }
```

or

```
          if(age<5)
              System.out.println("Are you learning how to tie your shoes?");

          if(age==5)
              System.out.println("You know how to tie your shoes!");

          if(age>5)
              System.out.println("YOU BETTER KNOW HOW TO TIE YOUR SHOES!");
```

Hope it helps